# Quickblox Video Chat User Creation

Tags: android, quickblox, android-sdk-tools, videochat

I am one year experienced person in android. I got a project to implement video chat on an app.
I used the following projetct code for the reference.

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk/tree/master/sample-videochat

But it doesn't contain a user creation(signup) programmatically.

So i included the following code for signup session.

```
private void RegisterUser(){
    progressDialog.show();
    final QBUser user = new QBUser("username", "password");
    user.setFacebookId("123456");
    user.setTwitterId("123456");
    user.setEmail("info@domain.com");
    user.setFullName("Full Name");
    user.setPhone("+911234234456");
    StringifyArrayList<String> tags = new StringifyArrayList<String>();
    tags.add("car");
    tags.add("man");
    user.setTags(tags);
    user.setWebsite("www.domain.com");       
    QBUsers.signUp(user, new QBCallbackImpl() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Result result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if (result.isSuccess()) {
                QBUserResult qbUserResult = (QBUserResult) result;
                Log.d("Registration was successful","user: " + qbUserResult.getUser().toString());
            } else {
                Log.e("Errors",result.getErrors().toString()); 
            }
        }
        }
    ); 
}
```

But while executing the  RegisterUser()

i got the following error

```
08-19 10:46:56.696: E/NativeCrypto(9664): ssl=0x52949540 cert_verify_callback        x509_store_ctx=0x52ea7ab8 arg=0x0
08-19 10:46:56.697: E/NativeCrypto(9664): ssl=0x52949540 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=DHE_RSA
08-19 10:46:57.443: E/Errors(9664): [Token is required]
```

Please anyone can give me a solution for this or a code for programmatically signup on QuickBlox...?!

Comment: Check here http://assist.quickblox.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/50/14/i-receive-token-is-required-error

Answer (score 1):

when start your application to first autheticate your app with your quickblox account after you signup.
1.create Application class in your app.

```
public class VideoChatApplication extends Application {

       @Override
       public void onCreate() {
       super.onCreate();

              QBSettings.getInstance().fastConfigInit(Constant.APP_ID,
            Constant.AUTH_KEY, Constant.AUTH_SECRET);
      }

   }
```

2 define your application class in your manifest file

```
<application
    android:name=".VideoChatApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
  <activity
        android:name=".Signup"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity></application>
```

3.sign up the user

```
QBAuth.createSession(new QBEntityCallback<QBSession>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onError(List<String> arg0) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess() {
                            System.out.println("session is created");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QBSession arg0, Bundle arg1) {

                            // signup code you must signup first

                            final QBUser quser = new QBUser(
                                    "Username","password");
                            quser.setFullName("fullname");

                            QBUsers.signUp(quser,
                                    new QBEntityCallbackImpl<QBUser>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onSuccess(QBUser quser,
                                                Bundle args) {

                                            //login success
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onError(
                                                List<String> errors) {
                                            Toast.makeText(
                                                    getApplicationContext(),
                                                    "call onError"
                                                            + errors.toString(),
                                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                                    .show();
                                            if (errors.toString()
                                                    .equals("")) {
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });

                        }

                    });
```